# How to write value to BLE device from iPhone using blemanager?

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth-lowenergy

```
- (void)bleManagerPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didUpdateValueForCharacteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic error:(NSError *)error
{
    NSString * str = @"0A0B";
    NSString * hexStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[NSData dataWithBytes:[str cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                                                        length:strlen([str cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding])]];

    for(NSString * toRemove in [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"<", @">", @" ", nil])
        hexStr = [hexStr stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:toRemove withString:@""];

    NSData *data =  [hexStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [peripheral setNotifyValue:YES forCharacteristic:characteristic];

    [peripheral writeValue:data forCharacteristic:characteristic type:CBCharacteristicWriteWithResponse];
}
```

I want to send a message or command to BLE machine like Tea-Maker Machine but device is not responding to my message and I am getting following error:

> Error Domain=CBATTErrorDomain Code=3 "Writing is not permitted." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Writing is not permitted.}

My question is how to send data from our iOS app (iPhone) to the BLE machine by using blemanager?

Comment: The error is saying you can't write on that characteristic. Else I think that the way you are constructing data could be really improved.

Comment: but how do I provide write permissios

Comment: What is the other device? Is it another iDevice? If on their part they didn't set the property to write on that characteristic, it means you can't write on it. That's seems logic.

Comment: there is a device which makes tea.  I means to say there is tea maker.

we have to send command to select mug and blow or brew water 
up to how much degree on the base of our commands it wil ask questions to the brewchime display.

Comment: The API doesn't seem to allow you writing on that characteristic.

Comment: I have BLEManager library

Comment: there would be some mechanisms to set permissions from code or from ble device

Comment: What's that? What I'm saying, is that if the implementation of the Bluetooth Low-energy Stack on that Tea-Maker Machine didn't set it's property to be writable by third party, you won't be able to write on it. It will just reject you.

Comment: bro i can connect it

Comment: just when i send anything at that time i am not getting anything on the display of that machine

Comment: It's not because you "can connect" that you can write on it. You can connect to Google.com, but you can't override the code of that page you can't write on it.

Comment: now what do i have to do then do i . have to tell to client that have u given write permission>? is it?

Comment: Yes, or maybe read carefully their doc. You might have to write something else before? Or you have a specific char to for writing?

Comment: in theie document they have just written like 

    [_bleManager sendDataToDevice1:@“0x0A” device:cb];

Comment: And are you sure that it's on THAT CBCharacteristic?

Comment: means? > I did not get it man

Comment: btw i dont know how many characterics that device provides us?

Comment: Ask the client. Your question is too broad

Comment: but bro are you sure that write permission would have not been given in deivce?

Comment: Print the UUID of the Characteristic. Prints its properties.

Comment: I can be able to fetch uuid